# How to close a modal when going back

Tags: javascript, css, modal-dialog

in the page department_edit.php i have a modal that shows all users in a certain department, and you can access the users from modal, the modal is activated by

`<a href="#openModal">`

scenario:
1. Press button to activate modal.
2. edit a user.
3. press back button.
 the #openModal is still on the URL. how do i prevent that from happening when a users goes back?

Answer (score 0):

A quick solution would be to use the onClick event to open the dialog, and set the href to "javascript:;". This will avoid changing the location.

```
<a href="javascript:;" onclick="openMyDialog()">Lorem ipsum</a>
```